# How do I do a function input in JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript

So, I'm trying to make a function for each jQuery AJAX call I do, but I have run into a problem. With the success call, It runs the function passed, however I need an "onsuccess" in the function. Simplified JS:

```
function ajaxCall(namef, dataf, onscss) {
    //do ajax stuff
    onsuccess: run(onscss)

}

ajaxCall("foo", "bar", function(){
//do code
})
```

So how do I do that? I have had that problem for a while, so an answer would be *extremely* helpful!

Comment: You need to include a more complete example of your issue.

Comment: What is `run()`?

Comment: It's just an example.

Comment: Never heard of `onsuccess`

Comment: An incomplete example.

Comment: I’m removing my question. This happens every time I try to post!

Comment: Then I would suggest you consider why that is.  We cannot inspect your code to identify what you did wrong, if you do not provide the logic that you did.  To expect otherwise doesn't make sense.

Comment: So you should read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply pass the value of `onscss` as the value of the `success:` option to the `jQuery.ajax()` call.

```
function ajaxCall(namef, dataf, onscss) {
    $.ajax({
        // ... other options
        success: onscss
    });
}
```

If you need to process the parameters, you can use an anonymous function that calls `onscss()`.

```
function ajaxCall(namef, dataf, onscss) {
    $.ajax({
        // ... other options
        success: function(data) {
            // ... other code
            onscss()
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX calls, and most other api/data fetching functions are asynchronous operations, so we need to call the onsuccess function when we get a response from the AJAX call.
here I would suggest you define onsuccess as a function and then use .then/catch to handle the calling of onsuccess.

```
function onsuccess(){
//what you want to do when you get a successful request
}
//make your AJAX call here 
AJAX()
.then(()=>{

onsuccess()

}).catch(()=>{

console.log("there was an error making the AJAX call")

})
```